# How do I read a xml file(from same directory) in Angular 2

Tags: xml, angular

I am trying to read data from a xml file in Angular 2.

Below is the code I am trying(as suggested on forums).

```
 constructor(private http: Http) {

        this.http.get('config.xml')
                .subscribe(res => console.log(res));

      }
```

But I am getting 404 error for the file.

Is there something I am missing.

Thanks for help.

Comment: If this works as was suggested it's likely your path is just wrong. Have you tried `'./config.xml'`? It's likely expecting the item to be in your `src` folder.

Comment: It is in src folder

Comment: You said you're trying to read it from the same directory though. If you're making this all from src you're gonna have a bad time. If possible add it to your assets folder, and then you don't need to make an http request.

Comment: For PoC purpose I have added that file in all the folders. Just trying to find a way

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while ago and i solved it by putting the file in the assets folder

```
constructor(private http: Http) {

    this.http.get('assets/config.xml')
            .subscribe(res => console.log(res));

}
```

This should solve your problem